# Java error---cannot find symbol symbol : constructor (seems to be the new keyword)

Tags: java

Beginners question because this is my first time attempting to program with Java.

I have a folder that contains my program `Program.java` and a folder called `football`, meant to hold my package. It has the files `football/Team.java` and `football/Game.java`.

Here is the contents of my files:

`Program.java`

```
import football.*;
public class Program{
    public static void main(){
        Team homeTeam=new football.Team("MIN","Minnesota","Vikings");
        Team awayTeam=new football.Team("MIN","Minnesota","Vikings");
        Game game=new football.Game(homeTeam,awayTeam);
    }
}
```

`football/Game.java`

```
package football;
public class Game{
    public static void Game(Team homeTeam,Team awayTeam){

    }
}
```

`football/Team.java`

```
package football;
public class Team{
    public static void Team(String abbr, String city, String mascot){

    }
}
```

I tried to compile my program by running in the Terminal `javac Program.java` and I got:

```
Program.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Team(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class football.Team
        Team homeTeam=new football.Team("MIN","Minnesota","Vikings");
                      ^
```

Can someone tell me where I went wrong with this code? What is wrong with the `new` operator here?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think this `public static void Game(Team homeTeam,Team awayTeam)` is and why do you think so?

Comment: You should use a IDE e.g. Eclipse or IntelliJ

Comment: Incidentally, as you have written `import football.*;` you don't need to prefix the types with `football` like `new football.Team...`, you can just do `new Team...`

Comment: @MuratK. IMHO I would encourage people to learn with notepad/sublime text (or vim if you know it already) and the compiler so that the basic language rules become intuitive, before then moving on to auto completion and intellisense for daily coding.

Comment: I'm using SublimeText...I have experience with Javascript and PHP already---I just have to figure out these new conventions. I wanted to learn Java because I became frustrated with how loosely-typed these two languages were, but it seems strange how the constructor is named after the class. Still figuring things out. Thanks for your help Andy!

Comment: Also the last mistake I made was forgetting String[] args

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Team` (and `Game`) constructors are declared with the static keyword and a return type (i.e. as a method, not a constructor), change it to:

```
package football;
public class Team{
  public Team(String abbr, String city, String mascot){
  }
}
```

Constructors for non-generic types take the form (from [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)):

```
modifiers SimpleTypeName(FormalParameters)
```

I would also recommend reading [The Java Tutorials: Providing Constructors for Your Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)